# How to configure card so that all cards are the same width, no matter how hong the title of the movie is in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am using react native and am doing a movies app. Just had a question about how to make it so that all cards are the same width regardless how long the title of the movie expands. I have tried adding the overflow: "hidden" attribute but that doesnt do anything. I will show a picture of the issue. If you look at the top rated movie section, the spanish film's title is extremely long compared to other titles, this the card expands way further out. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState , useEffect} from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet , FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image} from "react-native";
import { Card, CardItem, Body } from 'native-base';
import axios from "axios";
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";
import globalStyles from "../styles/globalStyles";

const TopRatedMovies = (props) => {

    const [topRatedMovies, setTopRatedMovies] = useState([]);
     useEffect(()=> {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${props.api_key}`);
            setTopRatedMovies(response.data.results);
            console.log("LATEST RESULTSS",response.data.results)
        }

        fetchData();

    }, [])


    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text style={globalStyles.sectionHeaderFont}>Top Rated MOVIE</Text>
            <FlatList data={topRatedMovies} horizontal renderItem={({item})=> {
                return(
                    <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> props.navigation.navigate("MovieItem", {item})}>
                        <Card style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                            <Image source={{uri:`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/${item.poster_path}`}} style={{height: 100, width: 100}}/>
                        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                            <MovieItem item={item}/>
                            <Text>{`Date of release: ${item.release_date}`}</Text>
                        </View>
                        </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            }}/>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 2/8,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"flex-start"
    }
})

export default TopRatedMovies;
```

Comment: You don't use bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use FlexBox, With 1 and flexDirection column. or define width of your card
2. Wrap text with view and style text to flexGrow:1
   this will wrap text to next line.